# loop through a dynamic key of an object in a array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have 2 arrays. The one contains the name of all the keys of the 2nd array like the following.

```
    const additionalFields = ['phoneNumbers', 'ageOrDobs', 'genders', 'usernames', 'employments', 'educations', 'websites', 'affiliatedOrganizations'];

const fields= [{
    affiliatedOrganizations: []
    ageOrDobs: []
    educations: []
    emails: [{…}]
    employments: []
    genders: []
    locations: [{…}]
    names: [{…}]
    phoneNumbers: []
    usernames: []
    websites: []
}]
```

Now, I want to loop through the `additionalFields` based on the value I receive I want to check if the key of `fields` have length greater than 0. For example.. `fields.phonenNumbers.length > 0` but the key `phoneNumbers` will be coming from loop

```
additionalFields.map((opts) => {
     if(fields.opts.length > 0){ //this one doesn't work...
        //do something
     }
}
```

I am using typescript and fields have a interface related to the values in it as shown above. Please help me with this... thank you!!

Comment: `fields` is an array of a single object; you need something like `fields[0][opts].length > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation):

```js
additionalFields.map((opts) => {
  if(fields[opts].length > 0){ //this one doesn't work...
    //do something
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
const person = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}

const key = "firstname"
console.log(person[key]) // John
```